# How to send emails in Rails in production environment (heroku server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using this source code to send emails in heroku server but it doesn't:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 25,
  authentication: "plain",
  user_name: "support@gmail.com",
  password: ENV['PASSWORD'],
  enable_starttls_auto: false
}
```

Is there any mistake in my source code. I want to use a free way to send email in my project 
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about port 25 and starttls false? I'm pretty sure gmail requires TLS

Comment: I am not really sure as I am newbie to that, cn you give me the correct source code. Regards @SergioTulentsev

Comment: If you are really looking for some free email services then try something like mailgun or sendgrid which is much easier to setup and it will also reduce load on your server.

Comment: @Abhinay thank you but as i know sendgrid is not free, they just give free trial

Comment: @Rodrigo not promoting anyone but 10K free email per month (mailgun) or 100 free emails/day(sendgrid) looks good to me :)

Comment: Try setting `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` in `production.rb`. Although it should b true by default in production, but still you can give it a try.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that your Heroku server is not running background jobs. Are you using `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` in your mailer calls?

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge I am using just delivery_method and delivery_errors